# Como exibir uma informação (nome do domínio) usando PHP?

Tags: php

Como posso exibir uma informação no meu site utilizando `PHP`?

Estou criando um site pessoal, e quero fazer versões desse site em outras línguas.

O que acontece é que eu preciso setar o domínio do meu site para poder colocar nos links.

Eu estava usando um `include` e nos links `href=""`, eu colocava:

```
href="<?php include 'dominio.php'; ?>"
```

E dentro desse arquivo **dominio.php** tinha apenas um texto: `http://meusite.com`

Ou seja, no final das contas, era como se eu estivesse usando:

```
href="http://meusite.com"
```

Seria possível puxar mais de uma informação por um determinado arquivo?

Algo assim:

```
$dominio['brasil']=http://meusite.com.br;
$dominio['mexico']=http://meusite.com.mx;
$dominio['argentina']=http://meusite.com.ar;
```

E em cada versão eu utilizasse a opção correta.

***Exemplos:***

> No site brasileiro:
>   `href="<?php $dominio['brasil']; ?>"` **que é igual a** `href="http://meusite.com.br"`
>
> ---
>
> No site mexicano:
>   `href="<?php $dominio['mexico']; ?>"` **que é igual a** `href="http://meusite.com.mx"`

*Não sou expert em PHP xD

Não sei bem como se chama essa função, só sei que é comumente utilizado para fazer traduções de sites (que **NÃO** é o meu caso)

É só mais ou menos como eu acredito que seja.

Não estou dizendo que é assim que tem que ser feito e nem que está certo, só imagino que seja algo assim :)

> ***Resumindo:*** Terá que ser criado um arquivo, e dentro desse arquivo conterá as informações, e dependendo dessas informações, eu vou setar o domínio dentro do meu site (colocando um código que irá puxar apenas determinada informação, no caso o domínio correto). No caso, cada versão um domínio diferente, por isso que preciso disso.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que a solução mais simples, seria utilizar o link começando com uma barra `/`.

Por exemplo, se na sua página inicial você possui um link para a página contato. O caminho seria `http://meusite.com.br/contato` ou `http://meusite.com.mx/contato`. Na tag `a`, o atributo `href` ficaria assim:

```
<a href="/contato">Contato</a>
```

Dessa maneira, ao clicar ele 'pegaria' a raiz do site e adicionaria o `/contato` no final.

Se o usuário estiver na versão do Brasil, automaticamente o link seria `http://meusite.com.br/contato`. Se o usuário estiver na versão do México, o link seria `http://meusite.com.mx/contato`.

Conseguiu entender?

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Thiago :) Só que eu estou utilizando dentro de uma pasta, por isso que não está funcionando. Vou utilizar em outro projeto ;) abraço!

Comment: Seguindo essa lógica, você pode utilizar o caminho completo do link, por exemplo `http://meusite.com.br/contato/formulario/enviar` ficaria assim `<a href="/contato/formulario/enviar">Contato</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Há muitos modos de resolver..
Aqui vai um exemplo simples:

Arquivo php com os dominios (dominios.php):

```
<?php
$dominio['brasil']=http://meusite.com.br;
$dominio['mexico']=http://meusite.com.mx;
$dominio['argentina']=http://meusite.com.ar;
?>
```

Página do link:

```
<?php
include 'dominios.php';
?>

<a href="<?php echo $dominio['brasil']; ?>">link do site</a>
```

Comment: Não é exatamente o que ele fez?

Comment: ._. lol era só um exemplo, não funfa asdasddad

Comment: @PapaCharlie, se reparar bem, no exemplo do autor da pergunta falta o echo. Essa é a diferença.. hehehehehh

Answer (score 1):

Minha proposta é algo mais dinâmico usando `SERVER_NAME` para identificar a TLD da URL e manter os links no mesmo domínio ou forçar para outro domínio.

Basicamente,se você quiser apontar o link para outro domínio, basta usar os índices do array `$dominios`, caso contrário, mantenha o parâmetro em branco para que a url acompanhe a TLD do domínio atual.

<sub>Apenas um exemplo com uso de uma função bem simples. Incremente-a como necessário.</sub>

---

```
function url( $domain = null )
{
    $dominios['br'] = 'http://meusite.com.br';
    $dominios['mx'] = 'http://meusite.com.mx';
    $dominios['ar'] = 'http://meusite.com.ar';

    if( ! $domain )
    {
        $domain = explode( '.' , $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] );
        return $domains[ end( $domain ) ];
    }
    else
    {
        return $domains[ $domain ];
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso dinâmico mantendo a url apontando para o domínio atual:

```
echo '<a href="' . url() . '/contato.html' . '">link</a>';
```

Forçar a url para domínio do México:

```
echo '<a href="' . url('mx') . '/contato.html' . '">link</a>';
```

---

> OBS: Na minha opinião, *URL* poderia ser uma classe pois há outros métodos pertinentes, mas caso mantenha como função, observe que nessa linha `$domain = explode( '.' , $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] )` a variável `$domain` pode ser do tipo estática para evitar que sempre execute o *explode*.

Comment: Genial!........

Comment: Eu tinha duvidas se era isso mesmo que você precisava. Acabei esquecendo de comentar algumas linha, depois dou um *up*.

Comment: Só tem um problema. Esse echo antes do <a>.
Não seria melhor colocar o `echo` dentro do `href=` ?

Comment: Não, pois o echo '<a ...' vai imprimir o link concatenado com a função. Você também pode usar uma variável `$link = '<a href="' . url() . '/contato.html' . '">link</a>'`. Se o echo estiver dentro da função vai imprimir a url antes de criar o link.

Comment: Vou realizar alguns testes :D

Comment: Eu ia jogar no **ideone**, mas lá não roda `$_SERVER`.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui uma sugestão orientada à objetos.

dominios.php

```
class Dominios
{

  const BRASIL = "http://meusite.com.br";
  const MEXICO = "http://meusite.com.mx";
  const ARGENTINA = "http://meusite.com.ar";

  public static function getBrasil()
  {
    return self::BRASIL;
  }

  public static function getMexico()
  {
    return self::MEXICO;
  }

   public static function getArgentina()
  {
    return self::ARGENTINA;
  }

}
```

pagina.php

```
<?php include 'dominios.php'; ?>

<a href="<?php echo Dominios::BRASIL; ?>">link do site</a>
// OU
<a href="<?php echo Dominios::getBrasil(); ?>">link do site</a>
```

Se você ver que as respostar não estão solucionando o problema, por favor, reformule sua pergunta, porque pelo que da pra entender essas respostas, tanto a minha quanto as dos demais, resolvem sua questão.

Comment: Acho que é exatamente isso! Vou testar :D

Comment: Muito obrigado! Era o que eu precisava :)

Comment: Maravilha, boa sorte ae ;)